# Mysterious "cryptographic verification failure" error on macOS Sierra, Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, macos

I have just updated and right away getting this error:

> "error: A cryptographic verification failure has occurred."

Any ideas?

Edit: I have iOS 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution:-

How I did [Working for me]

Step 1:- Go to this folder - from your finder press option Go - > Go to Folder

then type your project path like this example:- Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yourprojectname/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos

Now you can see a window pop with list of available File, There you see yourApp.app file [ Don't do anything just wait for step 2].

Step 2:- Open new Terminal and type just cd then just drag step 1 yourApp.app to terminal, now you will get the path for the app, now press enter button.

Step 3:- Now type this command **

> xattr -rc .

Don't miss "."(Dot) press enter button.

That's it, Go to your Xcode project and clean and run again.

Comment: Works for me too! Could you explain what happens here?

Comment: from my point of view, making copy of the project and running same project with xcode make issue, if you keep your project in icloud drive and trying to run from that location also making issue. This is all about path miss match and cache path that you use before. so while doing these step you are clearing build path for the project this make your xcode project to run as new without taking cache.

Answer (score 0):

Many people are having code signing errors with the first beta of Xcode 8. I would recommend using Xcode 7.3 until the next beta comes out.

Answer (score 0):

From your project's root folder:

```js
  find . -type f -name '*.jpeg' -exec xattr -c {} \;
  find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec xattr -c {} \;
  find . -type f -name '*.png' -exec xattr -c {} \;
  find . -type f -name '*.json' -exec xattr -c {} \;
```