# CodeSign error when building Objective C app on XCode 8 / macOS Sierra

Tags: xcode8, codesign, macos-sierra

I maintain a pretty old Objective C, iOS app. After switching to Xcode 8 + Sierra, I started getting a CodeSign error:

> XXXXX.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not
>   allowed Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

I've been through the docs and also other questions here and **I'm aware of the** `xattr -rc .` **solution**. I've also tried finding individual files with attributes using `ls -alR@`. There are no more files with the `com.apple.FinderInfo` attribute, plus `xattr -rc .` would have cleared them anyway.

I set up a VM with El Capitan and Xcode 8 and I can build and sign there no problem, so somehow this is Sierra specific.

What I've tried:

1. `ls -alR@`, `xattr -rc .`, et all.
2. Rebooting
3. Deep clean + kill DerivedData
4. Made sure code is not in iCloud Drive

The same Xcode is able to build and sign a newer Swift app I'm working on.

How can I find which of the error cases applies to me? is it a "resource fork", "Finder information", or "similar detritus"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed - Code Sign Error in macOS Sierra Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/resource-fork-finder-information-or-similar-detritus-not-allowed-code-sign-e)

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `find . -type f -name '*.png' -exec xattr -c {} \;` on the root folder of your project
2. Go to Finder, press `cmd+shift+g`, navigate to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`, and delete all the folders there.
3. In Xcode, press `cmd+shift+k` to clean your project.

You should be good to rebuild and run your app again.

This problem is usually caused by image files previously edited using Adobe Photoshop.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I just tried this exactly. Technically what I had already done is equivalent as well. `xattr -rc` removes attributes from every file, not just pngs.

Comment: Be sure to try other image extensions that you may have in your project as well.  In my case, some .tif files were causing this problem.