# IOS swift build error - Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I receive the following error after I converted my code to Swift 3.

> CodeSign
>   DerivedData/Parliament/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parliament.app
>           cd /Users/shai/Desktop/IOS/Parliament/Parliament
>           export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>           export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"Signing
>   Identity:"-" /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none
>   Users/shai/Desktop/IOS/Parliament/Parliament/DerivedData/Parliament/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parliament.app
>       /Users/shai/Desktop/IOS/Parliament/Parliament/DerivedData/Parliament/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parliament.app:
>   resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
>       Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Can someone please help me? 
I couldn't find any solutions online :(

Thanks,
Shai

Attached Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Add more information please, there is no any error text here

Comment: You may wish to search for this message, which is part of your error message: "resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed" (for instance one hit is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39652867/1396265 - do those solutions already work for you?)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:)

The problem was that the project folder was on my desktop which with the new Sierra OS automatically backs up the folder to the iCloud.

Transferring the project folder to a local folder fixed the problem.