# XCode Codesign Error when Adding Images to Cocos2dx App

Tags: ios, xcode, codesign

[image]Looked at a number of codesigning issues with Xcode. I know exactly when my problem occurs and why it is occurring.

Xcode 8.3.3

Building a Cocos2dx 3.0 app

I add images from my local disk to the directory proj.ios_mac/ios then pull them into the Resources folder in the Xcode project. I then write some code to use them in making Sprites.

Suddenly Xcode fails to codesign the app and I can neither build for iPhone 5c or any of the simulators.

I remove the images from Xcode, delete them from the folder, comment out the code, and the builds without the codesign error.

Tried

```
$ xattr -rc
```

in the directory Proj/proj.ios_mac/

No idea what the issue is.

Comment: In terminal, Try : xattr -cr <path_to_app_bundle>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/code-sign-error-in-macos-sierra-xcode-8-3-3-resource-fork-finder-information/39667628#39667628

Comment: where is the bundle in an Xcode project

Comment: $ cd /Users/johnfrye/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ETInvasion-aifpbxpnjenodbcmfazgmtbhfgtv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ 
$ xattr -cr 
then try rebuild and failed

Comment: I mean give root folder. For example, your project: /Volumes/Development/Project/AngryBird, then in terminal execute, xattr -cr /Volumes/Development/Project/AngryBird

Comment: Tried that. Still failing. That's what I had meant in the original question when i did the xattr -rc.

Comment: After executing, Did you Clean Xcode and Build again, You tried it on DerivedData, instead of real project folder...

Comment: I have tried it on both the directory containing the .app file as well as the project folder. I have cleaned and tried to rebuild just after having run these commands. It still will not build.

Comment: post error screenshot from Xcode with console log

Comment: I have posted the screenshot of the output.

Comment: yes, its exactly same problem. Try Solution 2 in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/code-sign-error-in-macos-sierra-xcode-8-3-3-resource-fork-finder-information/39667628#39667628

Comment: do i need to do them one by one?

Comment: yeah it was solution 2 from that post. I dont know if the custom is to dock me reputation or make an answer pointing to that post... but that was the answer

Comment: did you solve problem? successfully resolved code sign issue ?

Comment: yes. Should I answer the question and link it to the other answer you provided?

Comment: Good to know that you solved issue. Its exactly same problem and answered already..Good to close this question :)