# Flutter failed to build sample iOS app on VS Code

Tags: ios, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator, flutter

I'm trying to build the Flutter sample project on VS code, but got this messages... The sample is building and running fine on Android device, and I also tried running the sample with Android Studio on iOS simulator which is also fine. It just doesn't work on VS Code. Has anyone meet the same issue?

**Flutter: v0.2.2**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...
Xcode build done
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
/Users/Sean/Documents/myapp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app:resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: What happens if you try running from the command line with `flutter run`? If you're still having issues could you open a case at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/new (or grab me - DanTup - in Gitter)?

Answer (score 3):

This is a new security measure in the Xcode build system.

You can go into details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667628/6622328

For a quick fix, just clean the app before rebuilding it (flutter clean).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you don't have XCode installed, or have enabled your Runner project for your developer ID.

Comment: I do have XCode installed, and I'm using simulator. Should not need developer ID, right?