# Unable to add images to image button in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, imagebutton, code-signing-certificate

I’m new for macOS app development I'm trying to add image button to my view and I wanna see image after the text, so I'm dragging & dropping image button to view controller and writing title and after that, in image section I choose my image.

But my issue is if I will choose the system images my project works perfectly but if I will import a file by clicking project name > add files to.. and importing png, jpg,jpeg file to my project and choosing this image Xcode gives me this error;

```
CodeSign build/Debug/test.app
    cd /Users/feora/Documents/apps/test
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Signing Identity:     "-"

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --entitlements /Users/feora/Documents/apps/test/build/test.build/Debug/test.build/test.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/feora/Documents/apps/test/build/Debug/test.app

/Users/feora/Documents/apps/test/build/Debug/test.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Something is wrong with [this page](https://pasteboard.co/Htkyvi7.png) but I can't find which one

Comment: Please be specific what you are trying to do. And where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: Hi Janu, thank you very much for your answer :) I just wanna add image box and able to see this image when I built project. I can build project without any error with system pictures. But when I add external images in my desktop with clicking "project name> add files to.." I receive this error. I don't know how I can be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you're add image file you're also adding some Finder metadata related to that image. If you've searched error you're getting at least a little bit, you'd have found answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667628/1236218).

Comment: Thanks Dan! :) I was trying to fix this issue for hours and I couldn't find the answer before. I've solved this issue with open terminal> go to app folder > paste this code" find . -type f -name '*.png' -exec xattr -c {} \;   " Thanks to you :)