# resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed on Flutter Ios

Tags: ios, swift, macos, flutter, dart

This is a Flutter project. I used Flavor and two different main file for dev and prod.

I got this error message when running on the Actual device. I didn't check on the simulator. How do I fix this issue?

I tried to fix this using this way. But not working. I don't I do it correct way. I am beginning for ios development. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667628/8822337

I tried this way too, I am in the ios folder
`xattr -lr pwd` and then    `xattr -cr pwd`

Error

```
CodeSign /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-eqlnuvcbgrvptadbnflmaqpmnpuk/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/Demo\ app\ Dev.app (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/myName/AndroidStudioProjects/demo_app/ios
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Signing Identity:     "Apple Development: My Name (3YT9RVYQUA)"
Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.demo.demo"
                      (f510aq0c-122c-3d99-c947-c2440s4bd06d)

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign F342223C2F11B79BD9B0B991D9E324B2A3F41B37 --entitlements /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-eqlnuvcbgrvptadbnflmaqpmnpuk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/Runner.build/demo\ app\ Dev.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-eqlnuvcbgrvptadbnflmaqpmnpuk/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/demo\ app\ Dev.app

/Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-eqlnuvcbgrvptadbnflmaqpmnpuk/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/demo app Dev.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

[image: click here to view signing and capabilities]

Prod Team is my company mail, 
Prod bundle identifier is com.demo.demo.prod, 
Dev Team is my company mail, 
Dev bundle identifier is com.demo.demo

Is it right? [image: Flutter target]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know you said you tried this already but just to double check did you try the solution with the path to your project directory this worked for me.

After looking at your error closer I believe this is your problem. Your Error:  Xcode - resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed. According to what I can determine can be fixed like this.

**Solution** 
Open terminal and execute this command where project_dir would be your flutter project

```
 xattr -cr <path_to_project_dir>
```

**Or**
Navigate to your projects root directory from within your terminal then execute this command

```
xattr -cr .
```

Comment: which `<path_to_project_dir>` between these two? `/Users/myName/AndroidStudioProjects/project_name` or `/Users/myName/AndroidStudioProjects/project_name/ios`?

Comment: first time not working. and also I tried some another solution from google. But now is working.. thanks

Comment: sorry for not answer not answering right away glad you it work for you

Comment: For whom still having issues - I've moved my folder away from the iCloud Drive/One Drive and executed the commands above