# embedAndSignPodAppleFrameworkForXcode failling building a KMM project on xCode

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, xcode14

I'm getting this issue when trying to Build the iosApp of a KMM project. Can anyone help?

> Task :shared:embedAndSignPodAppleFrameworkForXcode FAILED
> /Users/rrodrigues/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iosApp-ceehutcffarijmfonwdjiknmheak/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.app/Frameworks/shared.framework/shared: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':shared:embedAndSignPodAppleFrameworkForXcode'.

> Process 'command 'codesign'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: are you trying to build for device or simulator? `codesign` error usually means that you have signing problems, go to project -> signing and capabilities, select your team

Answer (score 0):

this fixed it

Execute below command in terminal : First goto projects root folder

```
 xattr -cr <path_to_project_dir>
```

Clean Xcode and Re-build.

Foun answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/code-sign-error-in-macos-monterey-xcode-resource-fork-finder-information-or)