# When publishing to iPhone I very often get this message: similar detritus not allowed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Usually this comes up the first time I try to publish:

```
app/Japanese 5/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/Japanese.app: resource fork, 
Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed (Japanese.iOS)
```

My solution is always to **do a clean all** and then try again. So makes me wonder. Why does clean all solve the problem every time?

Does anyone know why this happens and what I can do to make it not happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code signing no longer allows any file in an app bundle to have an extended attribute containing a resource fork or Finder info.

To see which files are causing this error, run this command in Terminal:

```
$ xattr -lr <path_to_app_bundle>
```

replacing  with the path to your actual app bundle.

And you can also remove all extended attributes from your app bundle with the xattr command:

```
$ xattr -cr <path_to_app_bundle>
```

For more information [click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1940/_index.html).

Comment: Can you tell me what would the <path_to_app_bundle> look like on a simple Xamarin install ?   thanks

Comment: <path_to_app_bundle> is your actual app bundle (Japanese.app) as per your question description, your app bundle path is **app/Japanese 5/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/Japanese.app**

Comment: @Anne3, Please let me know, is it helping or not?

Answer (score 3):

Seems it does not have to be necessarily related to Xamarin but rather to signing of application and so to iOS development itself. You could try already existing solutions for code signing issues in

[Code Sign Error in macOS High Sierra Xcode - resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/code-sign-error-in-macos-sierra-xcode-8-3-3-resource-fork-finder-information)

or

[Code Sign Error on macOS Sierra, Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840241/code-sign-error-on-macos-sierra-xcode-8)

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster way to find files that have extended attributes, the `-xattr` `find` flag:

```
find . -type f -xattr -exec xattr -c {} \;
```